# Data/record hit counter on webpage c#/sql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I have created a SQL database with the "item details" table and have a field called hits for each of the items. 
I have created a listbox on aspx webpage and populated it using c# code. I wanted to know how I can record the hits each time the user clicks on the item on the list box. Or do I need to create a button or something so if the user clicks specific item, it gets recoded for that item in the database. I also want the hits to increase each time the item gets clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you about the backend on what exactly should happen. Whenever there is a button click or anything which tells that a user has selected an item. You should do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTableName
    SET hits = hits+1
        WHERE (enter the condition which identifies the clicked item)
```

Front end is your choice whether you want to create button or a drop down box or anything.